# pandas- new calculated row for each unique string/group in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe `df` like:

```
GROUP  TYPE  COUNT
A       1     5
A       2     10
B       1     3
B       2     9
C       1     20
C       2     100
```

I would like to add a row for each group such that the new row calculates the quotient of `COUNT` where `TYPE` equals 2 and `COUNT` where `TYPE` equals 1 for each `GROUP` ala:

```
GROUP  TYPE  COUNT
A       1     5
A       2     10
A             .5
B       1     3
B       2     9
B             .33
C       1     20
C       2     100
C             .2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does every group always only have exactly 2 entries, one for each type?

Comment: sometimes a group have more than two `types` but I only want to divide `type` 2 by `type` 1

Comment: Okay, and there is only ever one row for each type within each group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='GROUP', columns='TYPE', values='COUNT')
df2['div'] = df2[1]/df2[2]
df2.reset_index().melt('GROUP').sort_values('GROUP')
```

Output:

```
  GROUP TYPE       value
0     A    1    5.000000
3     A    2   10.000000
6     A  div    0.500000
1     B    1    3.000000
4     B    2    9.000000
7     B  div    0.333333
2     C    1   20.000000
5     C    2  100.000000
8     C  div    0.200000
```

My approach would be to reshape the dataframe by pivoting, so every type has its own column. Then the division is very easy, and then by melting you reshape it back to the original shape.   In my opinion this is also a very readable solution.

Of course, if you prefer `np.nan` to `div` as a type, you can replace it very easily, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
s=df[df.TYPE.isin([1,2])].sort_values(['GROUP','TYPE']).groupby('GROUP').COUNT.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[1])
# I am sort and filter your original df ,to make they are ordered and only have type 1 and 2 
pd.concat([df,s.reset_index()]).sort_values('GROUP') 
# cancat your result back 

Out[77]: 
        COUNT GROUP  TYPE
0    5.000000     A   1.0
1   10.000000     A   2.0
0    0.500000     A   NaN
2    3.000000     B   1.0
3    9.000000     B   2.0
1    0.333333     B   NaN
4   20.000000     C   1.0
5  100.000000     C   2.0
2    0.200000     C   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add_quotient(x):
    last_row = x.iloc[-1]
    last_row['COUNT'] = x[x.TYPE == 1].COUNT.min() / x[x.TYPE == 2].COUNT.max()
    last_row['TYPE'] = np.nan
    return x.append(last_row)


print(df.groupby('GROUP').apply(add_quotient))
```

**Output**

```
        GROUP  TYPE       COUNT
GROUP                          
A     0     A   1.0    5.000000
      1     A   2.0   10.000000
      1     A   NaN    0.500000
B     2     B   1.0    3.000000
      3     B   2.0    9.000000
      3     B   NaN    0.333333
C     4     C   1.0   20.000000
      5     C   2.0  100.000000
      5     C   NaN    0.200000
```

Note that the function select the min of the `TYPE == 1` and the max of the `TYPE == 2`, in case there is more than one value per group. And the TYPE is set to `np.nan`, but that can be easily changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way first using `sort_values'  by '['GROUP', 'TYPE']`  so ensuring that `TYPE` `2` comes before `1` and then `GroupBy` `GROUP`.

Then use `first` and `last` to compute the quocient and outer merging with `df`:

```
g = df.sort_values(['GROUP', 'TYPE']).groupby('GROUP')
s = (g.first()/ g.nth(1)).COUNT.reset_index()
df.merge(s, on = ['GROUP','COUNT'], how='outer').fillna(' ').sort_values('GROUP')

   GROUP TYPE       COUNT
0     A    1    5.000000
1     A    2   10.000000
6     A         0.500000
2     B    1    3.000000
3     B    2    9.000000
7     B         0.333333
4     C    1   20.000000
5     C    2  100.000000
8     C         0.200000
```

Comment: This will only work if there are only two types, which the asker says in the comments will not always be the case.

Comment: What about `type 0`.  In general I'd avoid relative positioning